# Do we need an Upgrade Advisor app tag

Tags: discussion, tags

With the advent of Windows 10 Mobile, and with the release of the Upgrade Advisor app by [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com) to aid the delivery of the OS to eligible phones, questions are arising on the community, I think the tag upgrade-advisor would be of great use.

I, for one, am one who asked a [question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12811/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-the-windows-10-mobile-upgrade-on-an-eligible-phone) on which the tag might be included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate tag for upgrade advisor would be nice. We already have separate tags for apps such as [whatsapp](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp)(116 questions) and [facebook](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)(43 questions). Being an important app having a seperate tag for [upgrade-advisor](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade-advisor) would be nice.

But till now only your question contains the words **upgrade advisor**. 6 more answers contain the key word but tags are for questions so we can ignore them. So a new tag for [upgrade-advisor](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade-advisor) will not benefit the community in present.

My idea is "Once we have multiple quality questions (atleast 10 questions with upvotes) on this particular app we can have a separate tag. Until then we can wait"